# Python can't open a file in C:\Windows\System32\oobe\Info\backgrounds

Tags: python, windows, pygame

Windows 7 x64, Python 2.7. Trying to make a script to automatically change the logon background. I'm using pygame, an SDL wrapper for python, but the code should be self-explanatory:

```
import pygame
import os
image = pygame.image.load(os.path.normpath("C:/Users/nivekuil/Desktop/backgroundDefault.jpg"))
surface = pygame.Surface((1366,768))
surface.fill((255,255,255))
surface.blit(image, (0,0))
surface = pygame.image.save(surface, os.path.normpath("C:/Windows/System32/oobe/Info/backgrounds/backgroundDefault.jpg"))
```

Returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/nivekuil/Documents/background.py", line 8, in <module>
surface = pygame.image.save(surface, os.path.normpath("C:/Windows/System32/oobe/Info/backgrounds/backgroundDefault.jpg"))
error: SaveJPEG: could not open C:\Windows\System32\oobe\Info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg
```

I don't think this is a problem with pygame, as it works fine if I save it to somewhere like Desktop. I'm also running IDLE as an administrator, and I've also run the program as a task in Task Scheduler with "Run with highest privileges" checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution! As according to [this](http://www.driveridentifier.com/blog/?p=89) article, I replaced /System32/ with /Sysnative/ and all was well.